# Adding a gif image to Keynote for macOS

Tags: macos, graphics, keynote

I am trying to add an image from Giphy to a presentation in Keynote. It seems to indicate I can drag and drop, but this isn't working.

If I add an image pane all I get is a text address not the actual gif image - where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the image first (put in on your desktop or so) and then dragging it into your keynote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kevin is right. Not sure why Keynote wants to copy a link to media on drag from websites. Something to do with copyrights and attribution, I'm guessing. I'm not sure of your skill level, so I will try to be detailed (which may help someone else, as well).

Right-click (or control-click) the image you want. Choose 'Save image as...' and change the name of the image before saving. It appears the images on the site are named dynamically 'giphy.' Then, in Keynote, use the Media button to select 'Choose.' Navigate to the image and [insert].

Unless you want a big play button on the gif (or if the gif is not animated), you likely need to change the image's behavior in Keynote. Make sure the image is selected (if not, click it once) and on the right side you should see a few options. Click Movie and deselect the last option: 'Start movie on click.'

Answer (score 0):

When I open a new keynote file and then go to the media pulldown on the top of the keynote window, iI select the Image Gallery item. That inserts the following in my slide.

[image]

The black circle on the bottom right opens a finder like window to select your gif. Try inserting GIF this way and see if it works.